# Facebook like box "Open Graph type" error

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

I get this error:

`You supplied an Open Graph type via one of the supported meta tags, but the type you specified "link" is not valid.`

when I try to click like on a like box created for this page id: 159862427014

Comment: So how your meta tags look like?

Comment: This is the html code I'm using to display this:

<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=159862427014&amp;width=190&amp;connections=0&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=62" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:190px; height:62px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Yes, it's an iframe and no, I haven't tried XFMBL.

But mind you the error also shows on the facebook web:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue.

I already tried the XFMBL, and using iframe...

Currently, my HTML file has:

!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

body>

script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js" type="text/javascript">/script>

iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect.php?id=111387215578364&connections=10&stream=0&locale=en_US" allowtransparency="true" style="border: medium none; width: 300px; height: 240px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">/iframe>

(I had removed the initial < to allow to display the code)

Still receiving "You supplied an Open Graph type via one of the supported meta tags, but the type you specified "link" is not valid."

Thanks for help.

Rafael

Answer (score 1):

That's because "link" *actually isn't* a [supported OG type](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph#types).

Use the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to make sure your pages are formatted properly.

Comment: But I never specified "link" as an OG type anywhere. I only put the page id (159862427014) into the like box generator.
Are you saying that I need to make sure that the actual webpage (http://www.ejs.is) is "formatted properly"?